# Access to a classic reference of Dold-Puppe

Tags: reference-request, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy, duality, motivic-homotopy

There is an old reference that I am unable tofind. It is Dold-Puppe´s communication at a conference. More concretely, it is cited as:

A. Dold, D. Puppe: *Duality, trace and transfer*. Proceedings of the International Conference on Geometric Topology (Warsaw, 1978), PWN, Warsaw, 1980, pp. 81–102.

I don't know if it is due to  difficulties associated to the iron curtain but I find no online access to this (apart from the russian version).

My library could ask for it, but I don't like this. Not only it is a tedious and costly process (request, scan at other library, send, print/collect), but it will not solve the problem for people willing to access it after me (not to mention that they must belong to an institution). Since it seems to be the classic reference for their notion of duality I would like to ask:

**Is there a way to have online access to this reference?**

Comment: for reference, the russian version is [here](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/getFT.phtml?jrnid=tm&paperid=2435&what=fullt&option_lang=eng); the english translation has been scanned, it's [here](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.b5099792), but can not be downloaded because of copyright restrictions; I presume this leaves an interlibrary loan as the only (legal) option.

Comment: The paper should be in the book https://bookstore.ams.org/steklo-154/ published by the American Mathematical Society. AMS published the old Proceedings of the Steklov Institute. Starting from 2006, these belong to Springer.

Comment: http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/doldpup2.pdf